# PS1 turns on, plays for a while, then screen begins to glitch. What's happening?

Tags: ps1

Quick bit of background here:
It's Christmas 2022. My family and I are sitting in the living room. We've all bought gifts for each other. When we come upon a box that says "For the family." All 5 of us grab a part of the wrapping paper and tear it off all at once. It reveals a box that once was filled with dog treats. We open it. My father pulls out a PS1. Yes, PlayStation 1.

That's the story of why I have a PS1. For some reason, nobody has used it but me. (Ten pin alley, ford racing 1) This PS1 is not like any I've seen before. I'm used to seeing a dark grey box that says "Sony" on it. This must be a late-era one because it has a built-in screen.

Now to the point:

I was playing Ford racing 1. Which is my favorite game we own for this console. The PS1 is not hooked up to the TV, it is operating under the power of an external battery pack instead of the wall. All of a sudden, the screen begins to do that thing that VCR players used to do, where a transparent line went up and down the screen rather slowly.

I ignored this; I had played through worse before (don't ask).

It's what the console did next that earned my curiosity.

The transparent line going up and down the screen turned into a flashing white stripe. I did not know what this was. I thought "I swear if I get an error screen-" my thought stopped. Because now the white line had MULTIPLIED ITSELF and I had TEN WHITE LINES across my ENTIRE screen. The flash of the line turned into a glitchy type of look, and while I was amazed at the complexity of the formations the line took on, and to see it on such an old console, deep down I was afraid this was not normal and that the console might not be able to hold out much longer. I shut the console off.

I checked the disc, it had come from bookman's (bookman's is a used entertainment exchange store in Arizona. They're notorious for accidentally selling broken/defective products). The disc was not scratched, dirtied, or changed in any way. It was in perfect condition, in fact even better than any of our other discs. Now my curiosity had become frustration. If it wasn't the disc, then what was it? I checked the disc drive. I checked the reader. I checked the screen. I checked pretty much everything. This was the first time in my life I was actually angry that I saw a console of this age in absolutely perfect condition. I was angry because if I had seen damage that would have at least answered my questions.

but alas, it's still a mystery to me; WHY?

(I case you did not read this whole thing, please remember that this happened while the console was hooked up to the external battery and not the TV)

**UPDATE:** The console appears to do it with every game. And only when operating under it's own power and not the TV. To address the question from Fredy31, yes, it is that model, I did some research and it is apparently the 2000 re-design of the original console and I guess is the middle era between the PS1 and PS2.

**FINAL UPDATE (no need to answer just here for future readers):** recently we bought NFL blitz 2000 for the console. My brothers and father played it for hours on end. But the console was pulled up on the TV and not the screen. The console did something different. The console played the disc normally for about an hour or so. Then the console shut down and reset itself. Everything was normal for the main startup, orange diamond, Sony computer entertainment, yadda yadda ya. Then it went to the colorful PS symbol. It stayed there for longer than usual. Just as it loaded the game it crashed, reset, and repeated. Of course, I checked the console once more. Nothing. It was still the perfect, spotless, squeaky-clean PS1 system I'd already looked at. As I returned home, I wondered if it was the disc, the one component of the entire console I had not checked. It was true the disc was shipped without a case, so if the disc were scratched it would not have surprised me. So, the next day I went back to check the disc. Spotless. Honestly, I was more impressed that a caseless disc could be in good shape than I was frustrated to still not have an answer. I used the knowledge that answers from this question had given me. I told my brothers it might be the screen disrupting the entire system, although unlikely, there was a chance that since the PS1 itself is really only a 3-part system (console, game, and screen) that the fritzing component could be causing the whole system to go crazy. I disconnected the screen and battery pack from the console and plugged it into the wall and HDMI. Then, I opened the disc drive and removed the game. It was time for a quick test. I powered on the console. Once it was on, I put the disc back in. It ran. It loaded the game. The game did not crash. I had fixed it. I had fixed the console I knew so little about using just logic and an answer from a guy on the internet. I was impressed with myself.

Comment: For the PS model, is it this one? https://www.amazon.com/Sony-PSone-LCD-Screen-SCPH-131-playstation/dp/B00005QI2S Really tought the ones with built in screen were all homebrewed.

Comment: After reading the whole thing, here are my follow ups: But only with this game, or with others too? Does it still do it when connected to the TV?

Comment: @Fredy31 One link click, A play of every PS game I own, three battery charges, and many bottles of Gatorade later, I have edited the question to address these issues.

Comment: With your edited question: My best guess is that the screen is on the fritz.

Comment: Oh yeah and forgot to mention this part of the final update: We had no memory cards at the time. Recently, we got some and we've had no problems since. My new theory is the absence of memory may have caused NFL blitz to go haywire. The screen is likely the source of the other problems though.